# spaCy NLP extract intent using wordlist

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am following an example from the book Mastering spaCy, and I want to extract the intent of a sentence using a wordlist, using the following code:

```
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from collections import Counter
from spacy import displacy
import en_core_web_md
import pandas as pd
import spacy 

nlp = en_core_web_md.load()

doc = nlp("i want to make a reservation for a flight")
dObj =None
tVerb = None

# Extract the direct object and its transitive verb
for token in doc:
    if token.dep_ == "dobj":
        dObj = token
        tVerb = token.head

# Extract the helper verb
intentVerb = None
verbList = ["want", "like", "need", "order"]
if tVerb.text in verbList:
    intentVerb = tVerb
else:
    if tVerb.head.dep_ == "ROOT":
        helperVerb = tVerb.head

# Extract the object of the intent
intentObj = None
objList = ["flight", "meal", "booking"]

if dObj.text in objList:
      intentObj = dObj
else:
      for child in dObj.children:
        if child.dep_ == "prep":
            intentObj = list(child.children)[0]
            break
        elif child.dep_ == "compound":
            intentObj = child
            break 
print(intentVerb.text + intentObj.text.capitalize())
```

The desired outcome is

> wantFlight

but I got this error

```
34 print(intentVerb.text + intentObj.text.capitalize())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The error comes when I try to extract the helper verb

Any help will be appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
tVerb = None # <- init with None
```

---

```
for token in doc:
    if token.dep_ == "dobj":
        dObj = token
        tVerb = token.head # <- overwrites tVerb for each token, at the end 
                           # tverb will be the .head of 'flight'
```

---

```
verbList = ["want", "like", "need", "order"]
if tVerb.text in verbList:
    intentVerb = tVerb # <- 'flight' is not in verbList so intentVerb is never set 
                       # and still the init: None
```

---

```
print(intentVerb.text + intentObj.text.capitalize())  # <- None type has no attribute '.text' therefore you get your error.
```

As a general advise, look up debugging and ideally chose a IDE with debugging support.

Comment: Hi thank you I added the .text bit, but know I am getting this error ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' ``` in this bit ```if tVerb.text in verbList: ```

Comment: @Aureon adjusted my answer

Comment: Hi @Andreas I added the code bit, but still have the ```intentVerb.text``` has no attribute 'text', and by debugging the code the intentVerb variable has all the type the None value, instead of the "want" verb.  Hence I found that the code 
```for sentence in doc.sents:
    sentence.root.text``` returns the "want "verb, but still does not work.